# Index Error :Python

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in python programming.The following code while compiling gives an error:

```
T_[j] = line[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Please help

```
i=104
l=i+92
p_=dict()
T_=dict()
z_=dict()
H2O_VMR_=dict()
O3_VMR_=dict()
cov_H2O_VMR_=dict()
with open('chevallierl91_clear_q.txt') as f:
  for j in range(2,5000):
    for line in itertools.islice(f, i, l):
        line=line.split()
        p_[j] = line[0]
        T_[j] = line[1]
        z_[j] = line[2]
        H2O_VMR_[j] = line[3]
        O3_VMR_[j] = line[4]
        cov_H2O_VMR_[j]=np.cov(H2O_VMR_[j])
        print H2O_VMR_[j]
    i=l+2
    l=i+92
```

Comment: This means line does not contain values you expect (perhaps a blank line), and the line.split() call results in a list of only one element. I suggest printing line after you split it so you can see why it fails.

Comment: you can add `if len(line) < 5: continue` after split in your inner loop, then you definitely avoid this error, and you can check the result to find out if everything worked as you expected

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable comments...I printed the line after splitting it, and there was a blank line in the file coz of which I was not able to compile my code.now everything seems to be fine...Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly, but it's likely that

```
    line=line.split()
```

only returned a single result. As a result, the only element in the list was line[0].

As @TheoretiCAL commented, try printing your results to see what exactly is going on.

Comment: I have printed the line..and it seems der is a blank line in between,I have corrected it and now everything is good

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad you were able to solve your problem :)